# Ruby simple search form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As a ruby-on-rails beginner, I am creating a *very* simple app to test a search form.  Here is everything:

## Person Model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.search(search)
 if search
  all(:conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
 else
  all
 end
end

end
```

## Persons controller

```
class PersonsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @person = Person.search(params[:search])
 end
end
```

## Person#index

```
<h1>Persons#index</h1>

<%= form_tag persons_index_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
```

<% end %>

```
<div>
<% @person.each do |person| %>
<p><%= person.name %><p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

When I load the index and use the search form, I get this error:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Extracted source (around line #5):
3
4
5
6
7
8

```
def self.search(search)
 if search
  all(:conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
 else
  all
 end
```

No doubt I am making a simple mistake, any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried: `where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")` i am not sure but have you tried it ?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? In the latest version (4.2.1) the [`all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/all) method doesn't take any arguments. You're passing 1 argument, so that's why you get that error message. You should use `where` instead.

Comment: yes @Mischa, removed my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change you search method to:** (minified version)

```
def self.search(search)
  search.present? ? where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") : all
end
```

**Or your old method:** (your same old structure)

```
def self.search(search)
   if search.present?
     where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
   else
     all
   end
end
```

Comment: thank you, your version of the search method works, whereas mine does not